# Image height not working on php loop

Tags: php, html, css

Here's the div that manages the look of each item in the loop:

```
<div style="float:left;width:30%;padding:30px;height:auto;">
    <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team']; ?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:100%;">
    <h3>
        <?php echo $r['name']; ?>
    </h3>
    <div class="position">
        <?php echo $r['position']; ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $r['intro_text']; ?>
    <?php if ($r['learn_more_text']) { ?>
        <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name']); ?>">Learn More</a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($r['learn_more_text']) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name']); ?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

            <h3><?php echo $r['name']; ?></h3>
            <div class="position">
                <?php echo $r['position']; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="content">       
                <?php echo $r['learn_more_text']; ?>
            </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I set the height to a fixed number (eg: 450x), the images are aligned in a row.  But that will make the page non mobile responsive.  If I set the height to auto or to a percentage like 30%, the images become mobile responsive but they don't align.  I get 2 images that separate into different rows.

Also, I got 2 sections of image.  One is called Our Leadership and the other is called Our Team.  The section at the bottom is aligned correctly and is contained in a div.  The div above it refuses to be contained in a div.  If I wrap it in a div,  Only the first item wraps itself in the div.  I've no idea why.

eg:

```
<center>
    <div>
        <div>first item here</div>
    </div>
    <div>second item here</div>
    <div>third item here</div>
    <div>fourth item here</div>


    Here's the complete code for both sections:

    <center><h2>Our Leadership</h2></center>
    <center><div>
            <?php
            $people = get_field('people');
            $a = 0;
            foreach ($people as $r) {
                $a++;
                ?>
                <div style="float:left;width:30%;padding:30px;height:auto;">
                    <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team']; ?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:100%;">
                    <h3>
                        <?php echo $r['name']; ?>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="position">
                        <?php echo $r['position']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $r['intro_text']; ?>
                    <?php if ($r['learn_more_text']) { ?>
                        <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name']); ?>">Learn More</a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($r['learn_more_text']) { ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name']); ?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

                            <h3><?php echo $r['name']; ?></h3>
                            <div class="position">
                                <?php echo $r['position']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">       
                                <?php echo $r['learn_more_text']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div></center>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>


    <center><h2>Our Team</h2></center>
    <center><div>
            <?php
            $people2 = get_field('people_bottomsection');
            $a = 0;
            foreach ($people2 as $r) {
                $a++;
                ?>
                <div style="float:left;width:30%;padding:30px;height:auto;">
                    <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team']; ?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:100%;">
                    <h3>
                        <?php echo $r['name']; ?>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="position">
                        <?php echo $r['position']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $r['intro_text']; ?>
                    <?php if ($r['learn_more_text']) { ?>
                        <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name']); ?>">Learn More</a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($r['learn_more_text']) { ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name']); ?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

                            <h3><?php echo $r['name']; ?></h3>
                            <div class="position">
                                <?php echo $r['position']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">       
                                <?php echo $r['learn_more_text']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div></center>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

Check out the source code at: http://www.equitasmg.com/who-we-are-2/
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because the items in the loop are having different height. So, try adding a constant height to each item in the loop.

Eg:

```html
 <div style="float:left;width:30%;padding:30px;min-height:550px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  What solved the problem was shrinking down the titles for each person.  Some of the position titles were 3 lines long.  Made them 2 lines.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to wrap a <div> around the entire section.  I have a <div> but it is wrapping around the first item in the section.  Not sure why.  You can check the source code on the page to see what I am talking about: http://www.equitasmg.com/who-we-are-2/

Comment: @Newbie Coder - Glad you figured it out.